# Looking for a mathematical proof of stability in floating point arithmetic of CG - any reference?

Tags: linear-algebra, floating-point, stability, conjugate-gradient

I am looking for a reference - paper, book, discussion, anything that has a mathematical proof for stability of the conjugate gradient method in floating point arithmetic.

Something similar for modified Gram-Schmidt would be as good.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I presume you've already seen [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(80)90259-1), [this](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/ETNA/vol.13.2002/pp56-80.dir/pp56-80.html), and [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0045-7825(93)90079-D)...

Answer (score 4):

[The Lanczos and Conjugate Gradient algorithms: From Theory to Finite Precision Computations](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Lanczos_and_conjugate_gradient_algor.html?id=kvW1Q2CRJRQC) presents a thorough analysis of CG in finite precision arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

Some more references:

- [The Lanczos and conjugate gradient algorithms in ﬁnite precision arithmetic](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~strakos/download/2006_MeSt.pdf) , G. Meurant
- [Iterative methods for solving linear systems](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=1P3z8KgFToQC&pg=PA35&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4), A. Greenbaum